# How can I generate a report based on given data using openai model like gpt-3.5-turbo?

Tags: nlp, openai-api

Now I want to generate a report from financial data using openai model.
I have already developed Q&A system based on custom knowledge base using openai and pinecone.
It was done with text-davincii-003.
But to make a report from that answer, I think gpt-3.5-turbo is good.
Please help me if you are familiar with these field.
Thanks.

I have tried with openai.ChatCompletion.create() method.
But it doesn't work well.